# How to identify dependency chain endpoints.MapControllers is erroring on

Tags: .net, dependencies, .net-core-3.0

I have an API solution that's erroring out on Startup when MapControllers is called.

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

The error itself is

> **System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException**: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Could not load type 'MyNamespace.Result' from assembly 'MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I know this is tied to updates we've made in Nuget packages using the MyNamespace namespace.
The solution builds and I've been manually tracking into the dependency chains of Nuget packages without finding the missing update.

What I'm trying to find out is which chain of dependencies is leading to this error.  Any suggestions for pinning down what it's trying to load that still depends on the deprecated copy of my Nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a restore and have a look in your `obj/project_assets.json` - this contains a list of all packages which your project depends on (including transitive dependencies), and each of those is listed along with its (direct) dependencies.

You can use this to trace it back to a package you depend on directly

Comment: I'm not certain if this solved the specific question (managed to stumble across one another way), but it's a good resource to know about either way!